# What do you call a single header whose purpose is to include other header files?

Tags: c++, c, naming-conventions

I've seen this done before in various C++ libraries - namely Qt (QtCore, QtGui, etc.) and Irrlicht (irrlicht.h):

```
// file - mylibrary.h

#include "someclass1.h"
#include "someclass2.h"
#include "someclass3.h"
// and so on...
```

Obviously this exists for convenience - a programmer wishing to use the library only has to include one header instead of lots of different ones. My question is, is there a special name for this type of header file? Even if there's not an "official" name, what you you refer to it as? A "convenience header" or "module header" or something?

---

Names given so far (*with sources*):

- Convenience header ([Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/random/index.html))
- Master header ([Apple Official Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20100905125036/http://developer.apple.com:80/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html), [An MSDN blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/precompiled-header-files-in-visual-studio-2010/))
- Meta-header ([The Game Programming Wiki](http://www.andalucia-hotels.com/gpwikiorg/#What_Goes_in_a_Header_File))

User contributions (*no sources*):

- Header header ([Larry Watanabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118860/larry-watanabe))
- Umbrella header ([Chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50742/chuck))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a nice question :)

I've found some sources that call it **master header file**, e.g:

- [Apple Official Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20100905125036/http://developer.apple.com:80/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html)
- An [MSDN blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/precompiled-header-files-in-visual-studio-2010/)

When it is used to host headers for the header precompiler, it could be called **precompiler global header**:

- http://www.rfoinc.com/docs/qnx/watcom/compiler-tools/cpheader.html

However I don't think that there's a single widespread way to call it.

Comment: Hmm, "master header", I like that. :P

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it was the first answer with sources provided.

@Chuck Nothing against yours, but I think it's important to have sources on something like this. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's any official name, but the only one I've heard is "umbrella."

Answer (score 2):

convenience header

I have seen them referred to as convenience header files.  [Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/random/index.html) is one example from boost that I pull up with a quick google search.

---

meta-header

Never actually heard/seen someone call it a meta-header but the idea fits and is much easier to say than *umbrella* or *convenience*.  I even found a [reference](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Programming_Techniques:C/CPP_Header_File_Convention#What_Goes_in_a_Header_File) to that name with a google search.

Comment: Having only used Boost among the references given I think of it as "convenience header" too :)

Answer (score 2):

how about

**header header?**

:)

Answer (score 0):

I like "meta-header"  (which I just this second invented :-)